# Global site feed plugin/function for custom post type?

Tags: multisite, feed

Is there a well-coded plugin or function that will enable me to create a global feed for only one post type in a multisite setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you might be able to achieve your goal by combining the feeds of the posts you are interested and create a new feed this way? That's what I did for a multisite setup. In this setup I created a page template which would load the rss feed which I created using Simple Pie (to combine all rss feeds into one cached feed).